# How do I access a transformed openegl modelview matrix [tried glGetFloatv()]?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to rotate over the 'x' axis and save the transformed matrix so that I can use it to rotate further later; or over another axis from the already rotated perspective.

```
    //rotate
    glRotatef(yROT,model[0],model[4],model[8]);//front over right axis
        //save model
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model);
```

Unfortunately I noticed that openGL must buffer the transformations because the identity matrix is loaded to model.  Is there a work-around?

Why, oh God, would you do this?

I have been toying around with attempting to understand quaternions, euler, or axis rotation.  The concepts are not difficult but I have been having trouble with the math even after looking at examples *edit[and most of the open classes I have found either are not well documented for simpleton users or have restrictions on movement].

I decided to find a way to cheat.

edit*
By 'further later' I mean in the next loop of code.  In other words, yRot is the number of degrees I want my view to rotate from the saved perspective.

Comment: Are you actually in MODELVIEW matrix mode when you make the `glRotatef()` call?

Comment: Well, old, fixed function OpenGL has a stack of matrices, but that's probably not what you're running into.

Comment: "Are you actually in MODELVIEW matrix mode when you make the glRotatef() call?" I am; but I do not know how to push/pop what I need if that is an issue.  I am using the push and pop functions to move the objects I draw around. "Well, old, fixed function OpenGL has a stack of matrices, but that's probably not what you're running into."  I am using the old openGL, both because it had the most documentation for what I was trying to accomplish and because it was really easy to add to my QT Creator project.

Comment: The `glGetFloatv()` call will give you the top element on the matrix stack. If you e.g. after calling `glPushMatrix()`, `glRotatef()`, `glPopMatrix()`, your top element is whatever it was at the start, and will **not** include the rotation made in this sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: Don't bother with *glRotate* at all, they were never very pleasant to work with in the first place and no serious program did use them ever.

If you want to use the fixed function pipeline (= no shaders), use *glLoadMatrix* to load whatever transformation you currently need. With shaders you have to do the conceptually same with *glUniform* anyway.

Use a existing matrix math library, like *GLM*, *Eigen* or *linmath.h* to construct the transformation matrices. The nice benefit is, that you can make copies of a matrix at any point, so instead of fiddling with *glLoadIdentity*, *glPushMatrix* and *glPopMatrix* you just make copies where you need them and work from them.

BTW: There is no such thing as "models" in OpenGL. That's not how OpenGL works. OpenGL draws points, lines or triangles, one at a time, where each such called *primitive* is transformed individually to a position on the (screen) framebuffer and turned into pixels. Once a primitive has been processed OpenGL already forgot about it.